# How do I set up an ssh keypair for a web user with no home folder?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

The title basically says it all.

I have web user that needs to ssh a remote server. Said web user has no home folder. I have no root access to give it one. Has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Do you have full command line access when you connect via ssh? If so, what's your `cwd` when you login?

Comment: What is in their second to last field in /etc/passwd then?